# Incrementing the upper limit of range inside a loop doesn't make it run forever

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

I'm an intro computer science student working in Python 3.7.1.

We were working with "Additorials" where you take a number and take get the sum of the number plus every number before it.
Ie: for the number 10-- 10+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 = **55**

I had to write a program that performed this operation as a function. However, I did it in a way that shouldn't work, but it does.

```
def bigAdd(n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        n+=i
    return n
```

for example, if I input the number **10**, it returns ***55***

But... Why?

If the upper limit of this loop is `n`, and it is constantly being incremented by `i`, shouldn't it run forever because it is constantly raising its limit? Why does it return any answer, let alone the correct one?

Comment: The value of `n` is used once to create the range, any subsequent changes in value have no effect on the existing range.

Comment: The "range" object is created once when the loop is entered first and in turn produces an iterator once. Both isn't affected by changes of n afterwards.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile and [@]MichaelButscher - your comments are the answer to OP's question (the other answers are correctly shocked by the non-initialized + bad loop range working)

Comment: @Cireo The current top answer does mention it, but somehow calls it the “second question”... What do you mean by _correctly shocked_ ?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile the structure is non-intuitive, not to the point where it seems obfuscated or golfed a la `sum(range(2*x-1,0,-2))`, but `n` still is the parameter, the return and the loop boundary, and the order of addition is `n + 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n-1` (I see that this ordering is from his "Additorial" definition).  All this is not intended as a critique, I don't think it was deliberate

Comment: @Cireo What do you think about the answer which talks about immutability?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I think I've commented enough, worried that I am acting pedantically at the moment.

Comment: @Cireo I’m asking because _I_ have my doubts lol It’s not pedantic if something is misleading or flat out wrong.

Answer (score 22):

You are adding *to* `n`, which initially is `10` (or whichever upper bound you are using). Thus your result is indeed `10 (the initial value) + 0 + 1 + ... + 9 (from the range)`.

Having said that, I'd still recomment *not* using the initial value of `n` and instead getting the `sum` of `range(1, n+1)`, as that's *much* clearer.

```
>>> sum(range(1, n+1))
55
```

Or if you want to show off:

```
>>> n*(n+1)//2
55
```

---

About your second question:<sup>1</sup> No, the `range(0, n)` is evaluated only once, when the `for` loop is first entered, not in each iteration. You can think of the code as being roughly<sup>2</sup> equivalent to this:

```
r = range(0, n) # [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., n-2, n-1]
for i in r:
    n+=i
```

In particular, Python's `for ... in ...` loop is not the "typical" `for (initialization; condition; action)` loop known from Java, C, and others, but more akin to a "for-each" loop, iterating over each element of a given collections, generator, or other kind of iterable.

<sup>1)</sup> Which, I now realise, is actually your *actual* question...

<sup>2)</sup> Yes, a `range` does not create a list but a special kind of iterable, that's why I said "roughly".

Comment: You might want to explain what "range(0, n) is evaluated only once" actually means.

Answer (score 16):

`range(0,n)` is evaluated once *before* the loop is entered.

This isn't like a typical `for` loop from other languages that has a condition that is constantly checked. `range` returns a range object that produces numbers, and the upper limit is set when the range object is created. Changing `n` has no effect on the range object that's already been constructed.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `int` values are **immutable** and `range` captures that particular instance only once at the beginning.

When inside the loop, the variable `n` which was pointing to the value `10` initially is re-pointing everytime to a **new** `int` instance when you are adding some number to it. And since `range` is evaluated **only once** it keeps the reference to the original `int` instance `10`.

The `int` instance which is referenced by the `range` function at the beginning, is not at all mutated in the for-loop and is still pointing the `int` instance value of `10`.

That is why the loop is completed even though `n` is now pointing to a different number every time.

Try this example snippet, you can prove this:

```
def bigAdd(n):
    for i in range(0,n):
        #temp captures the int before the addition
        temp = n
        n+=i
        print(temp is n)
    return n
```

The output is:

```
bigAdd(10)
True
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
Out[8]: 55
```

The first line prints `True` as `10 + 0` is `10` so both are the same instance.

Comment: This i believe is the more correct answer especially in reference to OPs background in the question.

Comment: I think this answer is somewhat misleading, and the conclusion is incorrect.  As noted in @Carcigenicate's answer, the reason that modifying `n` doesn't matter is because `range` is evaluated once.  Using a mutable value would give the same effect.  `x = [n]; for i in range(0, x[0]): x[0]+= i` will also complete.

Comment: @Cireo I agree completely, _fantastic_ counterexample IMO.

Comment: @Cireo x[0] isn't a mutable value-- x is mutable and contains an immutable at index 0

Comment: `range(start, stop)` is a constructor. `stop` gets set to the value of n. `stop` is then holds it's own value--it's pointing to '10', not to n.

Comment: I think they're wondering why it doesn't work like something like this: `i=0; n=10; while i < n: n += i; i += 1` (with the both additions inside the loop) There's still immutable integers there, but the loop repeats indefinitely. And yes, the point that `range(a,b)` produces some sort of an object which in turn holds copies of the start and end values seems more to the point.

Comment: That said, the code in this answer is just confusing. You would expect the first print to also be `False`, but it's not!

Comment: The reason that the first statement prints true is not because `temp` and `n` are pointing at each other, the first statement prints true because the immutable object `10` was created in memory. The system remembers this immutable object, so now any time something is equal to "10", it points to that cached memory.

Comment: @Mars true, if range wasn't implemented in C then you could do tricks with objects that mutate when compared to something.  There are two points - `range` creates a list immediately (py27) and the required integer couldn't change anyway.

Comment: in other words, `a = 14`, `b = 14` then `a is b` will be true

Comment: @Cireo In py3, range doesn't create the list immediately anymore, but yes, `stop` is readonly

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it when you have `range(0,n)` you define a generator with upper limit `10`, because `n` was `10`, and after that the generator doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

The `range()` function returns a series of numbers on first instance. In your case, from 0 to n-1. So, if you call `bigAdd(10)`, you'll get numbers from 0 to 9.

The function then increments the originally-input number (in your case, 10) by the sum of all the smaller numbers (in this case, 0 + 1 + ... + 9) which is 45.
So, adding the 45 to the original 10 gives you 55.

Comment: That's true in py2, but not so in py3. Py3 will generate the numbers 1 at a time

Answer (score 1):

The [range function](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/) is taking a value of n as its upper bound which prevents the for loop from funning forever. The for loop stops when i has the same value as n (which in the example you gave is 10.

So your code

```
for i in range(0,n):
```

is the equivalent of saying "first let i have a value of 0, then on the next iteration of the loop, let i have a value of 1, ..... and so on until i has a value of 10".

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can solve this problem in a loop, but why not use the [Gaußsche Summenformel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9Fsche_Summenformel) (sorry for the German link, I couldn't find the english name of it), which is indeed

```
n (n+1)
-------
   2
```

Put this in a function and return the value:

```
def gaussian_sum(n):
    return (n * (n+1)) // 2
```

Comment: The result is always an integer, so `// 2` is better.

Comment: While a completely right answer when the question was "how can I compute this number", it completely ignores the understanding issue with the for loop.

Comment: @L.F. thanks, I added it.